# It wont execute the econd if part even though all variables are right?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to programm a website using php and HTML for school i created a script that should be used as log in. the problem it never executes the second if part. It works with the first when you log in as admin. however when you log in as student with name, first name and pin it only executes the last if part which redirects you to the log in again.

script

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

mysql_connect("","root");
mysql_select_db("projekt");
$PinOG = "SELECT PIN FROM log_in WHERE Name =" . $_POST["Name"] . " and 
NName =" . $_POST["NName"];
$NameOG = "SELECT Name FROM log_in WHERE NName =" . $_POST["NName"] . " and 
PIN =" . $_POST["Pin"];
$NNameOG = "SELECT NName FROM log_in WHERE Name =" . $_POST["Name"] . " and 
PIN =" . $_POST["Pin"];

$resN = mysql_query($NameOG);
$numN = mysql_num_rows($resN);

if ($_POST["Name"] == "Admin" and  $_POST["NName"] == "Admin" and 
$_POST["Pin"] == 1337){
    header("Location:http://localhost/Projekt/Dalkner.html");
    exit();

}
if ($_POST["Name"] == $NameOG and $_POST["NName"] == $_NNameOG and 
$_POST["Pin"] == $PinOG){
    $localtime = localtime();
    $localtime_assoc = localtime(time(), true);
    if ($localtime["6"] == 0 or $localtime["6"] == 6 or $localtime["6"] == 
1){
        $Day = "Montag";}
    if ($localtime["6"] == 2){
        $Day = "Dienstag";}
    if ($localtime["6"] == 3){
        $Day = "Mittwoch";}
    if ($localtime["6"] == 4){
        $Day = "Donnerstag";}
    if ($localtime["6"] == 3){
        $Day = "Freitag";}

    $Week = strftime("%V");
    if ($Week % 2){
        $SP = "spgm";
        $SPO = "spg";
        $RP = "rpgm";
        $RPO = "rpg";
    } else {
        $SP = "spum";
        $SPO = "spu";
        $RP = "rpum";
        $RPO = "rpu";
    }
    $commandEX = "mysqldump -u -p " .$SPO. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG > 
$SP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG.".sql";
    exec($commandEX);
    $commandIM = "mysql -u -p " .$SP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG < $SP. "_" 
.$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG.".sql";
    exec($commandIM);

    $Kurs = "SELECT Kurs FROM Lehrerf, kurse WHERE Lehrer = Lehrerf";
    $resK = mysql_query($Kurs);
    $numK = mysql_num_rows($resK);

    if ($numK != 0){

        mysql_query("UPDATE" .$SP."_".$NameOG."_".$NNameOG . " Set NULL 
WHERE " . $Day . " = " . $Kurs);
    }

    $commandREX = "mysqldump -u -p " .$RPO. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG > 
$RP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG.".sql";
    exec($commandREX);
    $commandRIM = "mysql -u -p " .$RP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG < $RP. 
"_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG.".sql";
    exec($commandRIM);

    $RLength = "SELECT RaumNeu FROM RaumÄ";

    $resL = mysql_query($RLength);
    $numL = mysql_num_rows($resL);

    if ( $NumL != 0){

        while ( $numL != 0){

            $RaumNeu = "SELECT RaumNeu FROM RaumÄ WHERE idx = " . $numL;
            $RaumAlt = "SELECT RaumAlt FROM RaumÄ WHERE idx = " . $numL;
            if (mysql_num_rows($RaumNeu) === 0){
                $numL = $numL - 1;
            }else{
                $RaumN = "SELECT RaumNeu FROM RaumÄ WHERE idx = " . $numL;
                $RaumA = "SELECT RaumAlt FROM RaumÄ WHERE idx = " . $numL;
                mysql_query("UPDATE" .$Rp."_".$NameOG."_".$NNameOG . " Set " 
. $Day . " = " . $RaumN . " WHERE " . $Day . " = " .$RaumA);
                $numL = $numL - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    $Vplan = "Select" . $Day . ", Stunden FROM " . $SP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" 
.$NNameOG . " ORDER BY stunden DESC";
    echo "<P>" . $Vplan . "</P>";
    $VplanR = "Select" . $Day .  " FROM " . $RP. "_" .$NameOG. "_" .$NNameOG 
. " ORDER BY stunden DESC";
    echo "<PR>" . $VplanR . "</PR>";

}
if ( $numN == 0 ){
    header("Location:http://localhost/Projekt/Log_in.html") ;
    exit();
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I really dont know why it does not execute the second part. However i can guaranteee that the variables typed into log in and the database match perfectly.

Comment: You compare to query string, not to fetched results?

Comment: Is your school really teaching you to use the old, deprecated, insecure `mysql_` API? If so they are **stealing your tuition money and your time**. Stupid professor tricks never cease to amaze.

Comment: Yeah he wants us too use the old version wehre MYSQLI isnt included. But how can i chnage the fact that NameOG etc are this type ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of code you've posted.  Two things are visible to me.

Here's one. Your redirect to the login page at the end of your program depends ONLY on getting a zero-row result set at the beginning of your program. In order for this result set to have a nonzero number of rows, both `NName` and `PIN` must match.  I can't tell from your logic whether that's the correct behavior.

```
$NameOG = "SELECT Name FROM log_in WHERE NName =" . $_POST["NName"] . " and PIN =" . $_POST["Pin"];
...
$resN = mysql_query($NameOG);
$numN = mysql_num_rows($resN);
...
if ( $numN == 0 ){
    header("Location:http://localhost/Projekt/Log_in.html") ;
    exit();
}
```

Here's another.

```
if ($_POST["Name"] == $NameOG and $_POST["NName"] == $_NNameOG and $_POST["Pin"] == $PinOG){
  ...
```

I can't see where `$_NNameOG` is defined. I can see where `$NameOG` and `$PinOG` are defined. They are text strings containing `SELECT` queries. So the `==` tests will never come up true. So this code appears incorrect.

For example, the value of `$NameOG` is this text string.

```
 SELECT Name FROM log_in WHERE NName = yadda yadda and PIN = 1234;
```

So, when you run this `if` statement:

```
if ($_POST["Name"] == $NameOG ... )
```

you're actually doing this comparison.

```
if ('yadda yadda' == 'SELECT Name FROM log_in WHERE NName = yadda yadda and PIN = 1234;' ... )
```

That never comes up true.

You have to execute the SQL query for which the text string is stored in `$NameOG`, then retrieve the result set.

With respect, you need to develop a more detailed mental model of what's going on between php and SQL in your program before you'll be able to get all this stuff working.

Comment: Ty for you help. $NnameOG is defined directly beneath $NameOG. What should I do instead of using "==" then so this comes out true, do i have to change the way $NameOG etc. are defined?

Comment: What is the type of the variable that u get back from the sql statement and how do i change it to an string

Comment: Vielen Dank Problem hat sich gelöst. Ich hatte zudem im Code noch die hochkommata um die $_post variablen vergessen.

Comment: Auf Englisch hier, bitte. ** --> **   Thank you, I solved my problem.  I also had forgotten to place quotes around the `$_POST` variable.